# wanted to copy specific text from the text file and keep it in one temp variable how to do that

Tags: batch-file

hi all I am very much new to writing batch  file i wanted to copy 20170809 and keep it in one temp variable so that i can use that value further.
like in if key = SyncVersion then copy value in temp variable. 
can we copy 20170809 and keep it in one temp variable is it possible.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SyncVersion" value="20170809" />
  <add key="BuildVersion" value="20170809.01" />
  <add key="SA_Prefix" value="" />
  <add key="SW_Prefix" value="" />
  <add key="ST_Prefix" value="" />
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

[image]

Comment: @Magoo: did you really re-type the data? Go get some hobbies... `;)`

Comment: @stephan: No - OP's original post had a link but was followed by the XML sans newlines, so I just inserted the newlines and marked it as code. Since it was XML, it didn't originally show up in OP's post as it wasn't marked as code.

Comment: @Magoo I see. Hopefully there *are* linebreaks. Without them, my answer won't work.

Comment: @Stephan : There were according to the graphic which I've now included. Of course, the question of those newlines being windows or unix-style is an unknown.

Comment: @Stephan if the value is in /* 20170809 */ format then how do I get the value, /* 20170809 */ in variable ver sorry while explaining I was wrongly explained to you.

Comment: Your question basically seems to be: "how to extract a string, that I don't exactly show you from a file that I also won't show you?". How shall we answer that?

Comment: @Stephan thanks for your response I got it in the format in which I  wanted...  Can I replace the Value 20170809 by some other value which i will send through the prompt... Is it possible

Comment: uh - batch is not the right tool for that. That means, it *can*  be done, but it's a lot of pain and headache. Search for `JREPL.BAT`, which should be able to do what you want.

Comment: @Stephan I dont think so as it is very difficult means m not aware but i just wanted that if you found particular text in the text file just replace that string with the another String or Text.. I think I have not explained you properly before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the correct line with `find` and extract the value with proper tokens and delimiters:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims==/" %%a in ('find "SyncVersion" t.txt') do set "ver=%%~a
echo Version is %ver%.
```

Note: the syntax of the `set` command seems quite strange, but it's working, because the trailing space in `%%a`. `%%~a`, which is meant to remove surrounding quotes removes only the starting `"`. The last `"` isn't removed because of the trailing space. So the `set` syntax gets perfectly valid after parsing and even removes the (unwanted) space.

Comment: Thanks this works perfect.. but if the value is in "/* 20170809 */" format then how do I get the value,  /* 20170809 */ in variable ver sorry while explaining I was wrongly explained to you..

Comment: Is the data in your question wrong or do you just need to add `/* ` and `/` to the output?

Comment: in variable ver want and after  Asterisk * there there space and then before  Asterisk there is space both side /* 20170809 */  it is Skipping the